# Use string as part of a file name inside includes

Tags: php, include, echo, constants

I am new to PHP, still learning, but I need help with this:

If I define a constant like this:

`<?php
$area = "New York";
?>`

Then I will create a file New-York.php.

I would like to use the constant "New York" inside this line:

`<?php include $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/includes/New-York.php"; ?>`

I will have a lot of different cities and I would like to avoid having to change the includes link for every page, but rather only define the constant $area.

Am I making sense and can that be done?

Thanking you all in advance.

Comment: Unrelated to your specific question, just a word of advice to help you in future googling endeavours: `$area` in this case is a **variable**, not a constant. A constant is immutable and would need to be set using the `define()` function. Your `$area` is mutable and can change value at any time you want it to.

Comment: Got it, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`str_replace()`](https://php.net/str_replace) to transform the space `" "` to `"-"`. Then, concatenate into your include path:

```
<?php
$area = "New York";
?>

<?php include $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/includes/".str_replace(' ','-',$area).".php"; ?>
```